# OutputDebugString capture

Tags: winapi, mutex, trace

In a previous question I asked about if any real-time enhanced versions of dbgview exist,
 and ended trying to write my own, which worked out well except for one small snag

```
 OpenMutex(MUTEX_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, "DBWinMutex")
```

returns a handle to this mutex, except it returns NULL on windows2003 , anyone know why
this might be the case ?

Comment: What's the error (from GetLastError)?

Comment: Mark Russinovich is famous for breaking the rules.  Got him in hot water with the Windows group at Microsoft, at least until they hired him.  Distinguishing characteristics of his code is do-the-impossible-but-useful and actually maintaining the code so it works on later versions of Windows.  And show-but-do-not-tell, other than through his books.  Having the utility behave differently on another version of Windows is entirely expected.  Sounds like a singleton app mutex btw.

Comment: There is [no need to add a signature](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures) to your posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mutex doesn't necessarily exist.  e.g. OutputDebugString attempts to create it, rather than open it.

Details here: http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/outputdebugstring.html

Comment: I just found the same link :)     http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/OutputDebugString.txt more to the point

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, I faced similar permission issue when trying to use open mutex in MEX file.
This worked for me:

```
auto str = TEXT("MutexTest");
HANDLE h1 = OpenMutex(SYNCHRONIZE, FALSE, str);
```